# Delay ColumnB's functions until ColumnA is complete

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet which consists of a database of matchups. But I have two columns with script functions that can take a lengthy amount of time to calculate, Win % and SOS.

```
Player | Win%  |  SOS
Joe    | 54.0% | 48.0%
Axel   | 54.0% | 48.0%
Jenny  | 42.0% | 54.0%
```

The SOS function depends on the Win% function to populate its cells before it can even begin it's task. Because of this, when the sheet loads the SOS cells will time out since it does not get its data in an efficient manner. This is caused by the SOS and Win% cells trying to load at the same time.

I can't *recalculate* the Win% in the SOS function since I would need to do that a number of times, to the point that it make upwards of 10 minutes to calculate one SOS cell.Is there a better way to deal with this? Perhaps delaying the SOS function from starting somehow until the entire column of Win% has completed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: More details like, if you are using custom functions or if you are running a script on open to calculate these values will help with the answer.

Comment: @jack I'm new to Google sheets, so I don't really know the ins and outs very well. But I built scripts to accomplish the calculations. They do the calculations on open, but is there another way to do the calculations?

Comment: could you share your code?